# Find the series {$a_i$}$_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}$ - Linear system course

Tags: electrical-engineering, linear-systems

I have a question. this is sub-question D:
Let $T${$x(t)$}$ = \int_{-\infty}^{t} [x(\tau) - x(\tau - 1)]d\tau$.
Consider the signal $x_3(t) = a_i, \forall t \in (i,i+1]$ and $\forall i \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Also, let $x_3(t)$ be a constant piecewise function.
Let $y_3(t) = T${$x_3(t)$}$ = t$.
Find the series {$a_i$}$_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}$.
Assume that $T$ is a Linear Time-Invariant (LTI) system ( we proved it earlier )

Any tip will be welcomed, since I really don't how to start.
Tried maybe doing the definition of $y_3(t)$, but I reached nothing with this.
Tried also maybe turning the integral to series of integral with $a_i - a_{i-1}$, also did not work.

It is a question I posted at mathstack exchange, I thought it belonged there, till I saw this stack-exchange and that there it lot of system questions here.
Can anyone help?